# Is Silverlight .Net? (read before deleting)

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, c#-4.0

I know this sounds like a dumb question, but it's to settle an argument a co-worker and I had about Silverlight.

To quote my co-worker "we'll be developing in Silverlight...we won't be doing much .Net development".

My reaction was to state that Silverlight is .net. Sure the packaging of the assemblies are different, but at the core both VMs/GCs are running the same code. Silverlight is just missing a large section of routines provided by the full .Net 4 profile.

My co-worker's argument is that Silverlight has its own set of VM/GC bugs and that over all the Silverlight VM is way less mature than the more robust full .Net VM.

Does anyone have some answers to this? Perhaps there's some documentation on this somewhere? If I'm wrong, I'll admit it. But I can't find anything that says I am wrong.

Comment: Silverlight has its own version of the CLR and mscorlib.  To what degree they have any source code in common with the desktop versions of them is undiscoverable.  Tooling is very different as well.  Right now the debugger doesn't work on my machine and I have no clue how to fix that.

Comment: Any documents to back that up? I've tried to find them and I can't seem to.

Comment: http://codebetter.com/patricksmacchia/2008/10/01/comparing-silverlight-and-the-net-framework/#

Comment: Its also interesting to note that Silverlight 1.0 did not have this tiny .NET framework. It wasn't until silverlight 2.0 that we could program with C# or other .NET programming languages, just javascript. Perhaps that's what your co-worker is referring to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Straight from the horse's mouth:

> Silverlight is a free plug-in, powered by the .NET framework

[Silverlight.net/GetStarted](http://www.silverlight.net/getstarted/)

I don't think you can get any more definitive than that.

Comment: My only comment to this would be, how do we know it's not a partial re-write/optimzation of the .NET framework that's used in Silverlight.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, Silverlight is .NET.

This issued is discussed in a different forum [here](http://faq.programmerworld.net/programming/silverlight.html).

This link, coupled with the MSDN link mentioned earlier should provide you with plenty of support for your argument.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I think your coworker is trying to sound smart without being very smart...

Silverlight has access to ALL of the .NET framework shared components.  He's splitting hairs about the graphical components that vary from the Winforms(WPF) platform.  With his rationale you can argue that ASP.NET isn't .NET because there is a different construct used for UI implementations.  I say just ignore him and if he's your boss check out http://careers.stackoverflow.com

Comment: That's a bit harsh.  I've never had a boss that knows more about development than I do.  Mgmnt has a different role then a dev.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey If he doesn't know much about development but still attempts to speak authoritatively about it, I'd say @Achilles's suggestion is fair.